# CRM Email attaching to wrong cases

Tags: dynamics-365

When a case is resolved in Dynamics 365 CRM a mail is triggered notifying customer that case has been resolved. But when customer replies to that same mail that email activity gets attached to a different case which is active. Is it because of tracking number? Can someone explain how this works?

Comment: how is your tracking been happening in crm, Is it token based or is it smart matching.
Read through these 2 articles which will give you more idea.
[Article 1](https://carldesouza.com/dynamics-365-automatic-email-tracking/)
[Article 2](https://itsolutions.bdo.ca/insights/automatic-email-tracking-in-dynamics-365-customer-engagement/)

Comment: If you are using Token Tracing based tracking, here is the solution for your [issue](https://thecrmwiz.com/2013/07/12/crm-e-mail-token-duplicates/)

Comment: Tracking is token based.

Comment: Just wanted to know that when case gets resolved and then reply mail is sent again to for that case then what happens to that email? Does it get attached to a different active case with same tracking number.? @AnkUser

Comment: Ideally it should attach to same case but if there is an duplicate token in system, crm will attach it to another case.

Comment: Did you managed to figure it out?